# How to get conditional formatting in Google Sheets if a cell contains specific formula/function?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to set conditional formatting in my GS for cells that *not only* are a formula, but have a specific type of formula.

I know I can do a conditional formatting to highlight cells that are formulas
e.g. Custom Formula = `=isformula(A1)`

But what if I want the conditional formatting only to apply to *certain* kinds of formulas?

e.g. if the cell contains a formula like `=A1+B1+C1`, then leave it alone
But if the cell contains a formula that uses the Sum function, e.g. `=SUM(A1:A5)`, then highlight it.

I tried to do Custom Formula = `=iferror(find("SUM",A1),false)` for the range `A1:D` but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [`FORMULATEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365792?hl=en) to analyze the formula in a specific cell. Something like this should work:

```
=NOT(ISERR(FIND("SUM(",FORMULATEXT(E17))))
```

[image]

(here F17 and F18 show the formulas of E17 resp. E18)

Comment: I wasn't even aware of such a function. Thanks!

Comment: And thanks for the suggested edits!